# Setting column from not null to null - mysql

Tags: mysql, null

For some reason, I have to change the default value of one parameter 'param' in a mysql table, I have to set it to NULL by default. I tried to manage it through phpmyadmin and I get this error message :

```
ALTER TABLE  `mytable` CHANGE  `param`  `param` VARCHAR( 150 ) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT NULL
```

How can I resolve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't set a `NOT NULL` column to have `DEFAULT NULL`.

In phpMyAdmin, check the `Null?` box for the column when editing it.

Comment: So thanks, it seems to work but I want some precision : I have to do that because my login system (facebook-connect, by email) is working fine except for twitter-connecting, since there is no last-name. So I have to set this value to null. Does the change you advised mecould have impact on some processes in my website ?

Comment: sorry I forgot something, I have to execute the same command on an mysql server that I can only reach by mysql command. Do you know the right syntax please ?

Comment: You already have it in your question, just remove the "NOT NULL" bit.

Comment: I don't want to bother you but I tried the syntax on my terminal, I dropped the quotes but it didn't work..., anyhelp would be great

Comment: Show me exactly what you're trying to run.

Comment: Here's ALTER TABLE  account CHANGE  a_lastname  a_lastname VARCHAR( 150 ) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NULL

Comment: You missed the word `DEFAULT`. Also, instead of `CHANGE` followed by the same name twice, use `MODIFY` and just put the column name once.

Comment: Use `show columns in account`. But usually no message means no error.